# How do I search inside a thread on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, search

I'm looking at faqs : https://stackoverflow.com/faq#searching

and https://stackoverflow.com/search

but I can't find a way to search inside long threads.

Comment: "Find on page" should do for the vast majority of questions. Granted, it won't work for multi-page questions but those are exceedingly rare anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the [search help](https://stackoverflow.com/search), you can use `inquestion:##` to search within a given question.

If you're viewing the question you wish to search in, you can use the shortcut `inquestion:this`, as in [this example: `inquestion:this "viewing"`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion%3Athis+%22viewing%22)